# how to implement MVCin c# tutorial in empty project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller

I have done simple projects by on MVC architecture by using the template in .net framework , Now I am trying to implement same architecture by creating an empty project. I searched to get tutorials or helping code but all in vain. Please guide me how can I Implement Model view control architecture in .NET framework C# by creating the empty project

Answer (score 0):

You can add it through NuGet, which will download and add references to all the libraries you need to run an MVC project.